# $.ajax is not a function in main.js electron

Tags: jquery, electron

I would make a async call in main.js on electron.
I tried to do with Jquery but return error `$.ajax is not a function`
I have tried with:

```
mainWindow.$ = mainWindow.jQuery = require('jquery');
let $ = mainWindow.$;
$.ajax({
   ....
})
```

But $.ajax is not a function.
How can I include correctly jquery?

Comment: According to the [documentation for the jQuery node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), "For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required.". I suggest using a different module such as `http` in place of `$.ajax`. If you really need jQuery in the Electron main process, you might be able to mock one with `jsdom`.

Comment: thankyou Justin, I have done as you suggested with http. and it Work!

Answer (score 1):

In Electron, you have to define the jQuery object yourself. This can be done with the following:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Place this in the **renderer** process (the one you link in your HTML file), and you should be fine.