# I am creating electron app and getting Uncaught Exception: TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, electron

I am creating electron app that hits an endpoint from API and shows the response on the page. Since electron separated the main process from the renderer process I have to use preload script to communicate between the two processes so I can update the page on load. I use jQuery AJAX to make async call to the API, but got error like this

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/***/***/***/***/main.js:41:7)
...
```

I put the AJAX call in the main.js. Here are some snippets from my code

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
let $ = require('jquery')

let text
let win

const createWindow = () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        // some code...
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html');
    win.webContents.send("showText", text);

    // code...
    
    ipcMain.on("receiveData", (event, formData) => {
    $.ajax({
        // code...
        }
    });
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

let postData = (formData) => {
    ipcRenderer.send("receiveData", formData)
}
let showText = (callback) => {
    ipcRenderer.on("showText", (callback))
}
let bridge = {postData: postData, showText: showText}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("bridge", bridge)
```

**renderer.js**

```
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    // code...
    window.bridge.postData(formData);
});

window.bridge.showText((event, text) => {
    $("#result").append(text)
});
```

Also I got this error in console, thought it somewhat related.

```
Error: Cannot bind an API on top of an existing property on the window object
    at Object.exposeInMainWorld (VM386 renderer_init:45:364)
```

I have tried importing jQuery and placing the AJAX in renderer according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42379667/16140882) but it didn't work because the renderer doesn't have access to node environment, I guess. I already have the regular build of jQuery instead of the slim one as said in many answers. Been searching many solutions about similar error but all of them didn't seem to work for me. I've only learnt electron days ago so perhaps there's something terribly obvious I have missed. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does not work in a NodeJS environment without a (mocked) DOM, as also explicitly stated on its [NPM documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery). You will either have to rely on NodeJS' own web request tools (such as the [`https` module](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v18/https/)) or use the solution provided in the NPM ReadMe of JQuery (using a third-party package to mock a window object).

---

Generally, it may be worthwile to read into [Electron's process model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model).